# Refused to load the script 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api' in my WordPress website

Tags: wordpress, content-security-policy

I've running a website which I've created in WordPress with using Betheme(Theme), I found an issue in chrome developer mode which is like this

`Refused to load the script 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' www.google-analytics.com ajax.googleapis.com www.googletagmanager.com www.google.com www.gstatic.com". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.`

I've tried with the Really Simple ssl(plugin), added this `url(https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api) in this plugin's **Frame Ancestors **` for additional domains which can embed my website.
[Really Simple SLL Plugins setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARip1.png)

Still it's not working after added.

what are the possible ways anyone can suggest?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to figure out where the Content Security Policy is set in your worpdress setup and update the script-src directive to be script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' [www.google-analytics.com](http://www.google-analytics.com) ajax.googleapis.com [www.googletagmanager.com](http://www.googletagmanager.com) [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) [www.gstatic.com](http://www.gstatic.com) www.youtube.com;"